# does it has sense to save all version of the code when two versions are compatible?

Tags: version-control, version, versioning

Imagine that I have my library 1.0.0.0 but I have detect a bug and I correct it in the version 1.0.0.1. A client tell me that he has detected a new bug in the version 1.0.0.0 because he is still using the version 1.0.0.0.

I think that the first thing that the client should to do it is first update to the version 1.0.0.1 because it is compatible with the version 1.0.0.0 so I will fix the bug in the version 1.0.0.2 from 1.0.0.1.

Anyway, although I have the code of the version 1.0.0.0, I can't modify this version, because if I fix the bug in the version 1.0.0.0, I can't create the new version of the 1.0.0.1 because it is exists and fix another bug. So at the end I have to release the version 1.0.0.2.

So, my question is, does it has sense to have all version of the code or just the versions that are incompatible whit the previews one? Because in this case, I have to support older versions because perhaps some  client can't update to the new one.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "save" or "have" them? You should save *all* substantial revisions in your version-control software, and *especially* all released versions. If you mean do you need to support 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1 when they are 100% compatible, then that's a marketing/customer relations decision, not a programming one, but I'd say no. If the update is free and 100% drop-in compatible, then just send them the update.

Comment: Yes, I mean that, that if the 1.0.0.1 and 1.0.0.2 is 100% compatible, if it is needed to have the code of the 1.0.0.1, because I will never change the 1.0.0.1 because in this case I would update 1.0.0.2 because has another fixes.

Comment: Why would you ever get rid of any code?

Comment: So do you mean that I would save all the code of all versions although to the client I will sent only the last version?